# How to get URL variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a URL that looks like this

```
http://example.com/b/cosmetics/cream
```

How do I get value **cosmetics, cream** from the URL using Javascript  and also alert it using javascript

Thanks

Comment: is that URL the current location? or is it just some string? For the latter, you could use the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) for non Microsoft browsers

Comment: really. important to know if you are dealing with the URL of the current page, or just a URL ... because most of the answers given blindly assume that's the URL of the current page

Comment: Question shows a complete lack of research effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use.

```
  <script>
  var path = location.pathname;
  var parts = path.split("/");
  alert(parts[2]);
  alert(parts[3]);
  </script>
```

then, you will value with `alert`.

`cosmetics`

`cream`

Comment: To do what? This doesn't produce results requested

Comment: How do I use this Location.pathname. can you give example with my URL above